# return statement shows undefined in the following ajax code

Tags: ajax

the following code shows undefined when i try to return the xml response to the calling function

```
<script>
var content="";
function ReadFile(filename){    
    var xmlo=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlo.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status == 200) {
            SendData(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlo.open("GET",filename,true);
    xmlo.send();    
}   

function SendData(content){
    return content;
}

document.write(ReadFile("test.txt"));
</script>
```

why does it happen?
and how should i solve the problem i am facing
i know i can directly use document.write in the SendData function. 
but i want to  return the data to any function calling it.
so please help on how to use the return statement here